# Replace Returned IDs with Value from another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one named Reservations and the other named Restaurants. Reservations has columns rid (restaurant ID), and Restaurants has fields rid and rname (restaurant name). I am trying to create a query that returns the names of all the restaurants whos rid occurs in Reservations less than 3 times. I know how to use COUNT and GROUP, but can't figure out how to then switch the rid with the name of the restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

Quick SQL would be like -

```
SELECT *
  FROM RESTAURANTS
 WHERE RID IN
       (SELECT RID FROM RESERVATIONS GROUP BY RID HAVING COUNT(*) < 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select r.*
from restaurants r
where (select count(*)
       from reservations re
       where re.rid = r.rid
      ) < 3;
```